# Sending audio to bluetooth speaker with bluealsa

Tags: sound, bluetooth, alsa

I have my NAS on the base of Cubietruck (Ubuntu Xenial with Armbian Linux 3.4.113-sun7i) with integrated bluetooth. Now I'm trying to send audio to my bluetooth speaker via bluealsa.

Initially I've used this manual to install and setup bluealsa: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/6480-bluealsa-bluetooth-audio-using-alsa-not-pulseaudio/

I've ended with same problem as I'm having now after recompiling and setting up bluealsa again using this manual: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90267/how-to-stream-sound-to-a-bluetooth-device-from-a-raspberry-pi-zero

which gave me a bit more progress, for example I can see such message while connecting to my bluetooth speaker: `[BH129]# bluealsa: D: ../../src/bluez.c:1267: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Objec                     tManager.InterfacesAdded()`

I didn't see such message when installed and setup bluealsa according to 1st manual.

I'm starting bluealsa first manually after boot. By the way is bluetooth-profile correct:  - hsp-hs      Headset (v1.2)?

```
 bluealsa -p hsp-hs &
```

Bluealsa seems to be running:

```
root@Artisan:~# ps -ef | grep bluealsa
root      2591  2557  0 15:16 pts/0    00:00:00 bluealsa -p hsp-hs
root      2803  2557  1 15:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bluealsa
```

Here's how I connect to my speaker:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 43:29:B1:55:01:01 Discovering: yes

[NEW] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 BH129
[bluetooth]# pair EB:06:EF:47:83:A6
Attempting to pair with EB:06:EF:47:83:A6
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 Class: 0x240404
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 Icon: audio-card
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 UUIDs: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# trust EB:06:EF:47:83:A6
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 Trusted: yes
Changing EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect EB:06:EF:47:83:A6
Attempting to connect to EB:06:EF:47:83:A6
[CHG] Device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6 Connected: yes
[BH129]# bluealsa: D: ../../src/bluez.c:1267: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded()
Connection successful
[BH129]# exit
[DEL] Controller 43:29:B1:55:01:01 BlueZ 5.37 [default]
```

Here's bluetooth status

```
root@Artisan:~# systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-12-18 15:13:37 UTC; 36min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1307 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1307 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap --plugin=a2dp

Dec 18 15:13:37 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Ignoring (cli) thermometer
Dec 18 15:13:37 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Ignoring (cli) heartrate
Dec 18 15:13:37 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Ignoring (cli) cyclingspeed
Dec 18 15:13:37 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Ignoring (cli) sixaxis
Dec 18 15:13:37 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Bluetooth management interface 1.0 initialized
Dec 18 15:13:37 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characterist
Dec 18 15:13:37 Artisan systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 18 15:14:36 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS
Dec 18 15:14:36 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS
Dec 18 15:14:40 Artisan bluetoothd[1307]: Ignoring unsupported UUID for addition
```

I was a bit confused with "Alsa config" section and ended with configuring it this way:

```
root@Artisan:~# cat /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/20-bluealsa.conf                                     # BlueALSA integration setup

defaults.bluealsa.service "org.bluealsa"
defaults.bluealsa.profile "a2dp"
defaults.bluealsa.delay 20000
defaults.bluealsa.battery "yes"

ctl.bluealsa {
        @args [ SRV BAT ]
        @args.SRV {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.service
                }
        }
        @args.BAT {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.battery
                }
        }
        type bluealsa
        service $SRV
        battery $BAT
}

pcm.bluealsa {
        @args [ SRV DEV PROFILE DELAY ]
        @args.SRV {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.service
                }
        }
        @args.DEV {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.device
                }
        }
        @args.PROFILE {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.profile
                }
        }
        @args.DELAY {
                type integer
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.delay
                }
        }
        type plug
        slave.pcm {
                type bluealsa
                service $SRV
                device $DEV
                profile $PROFILE
                delay $DELAY
        }
        hint {
                show {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.namehint.extended
                }
                description "Bluetooth Audio Hub"
        }
}

pcm {
        type bluealsa
        interface "hci0"
        device EB:06:EF:47:83:A6
        profile "a2dp"
}

ctl.!default {
        type bluealsa
        interface "hci0"
}
```

Here's ~/asoundrc

```
root@Artisan:~# cat ~/.asoundrc
defaults.bluealsa.interface "hci0"
defaults.bluealsa.device "EB:06:EF:47:83:A6"
defaults.bluealsa.profile "a2dp"
```

Here's what I get when I try to play mp3 file with aplay:

```
root@Artisan:~# aplay -D bluealsa:DEV=EB:06:EF:47:83:A6,PROFILE=a2dp,HCI=hci0 /ncsdata/Music/night.mp3
ALSA lib conf.c:4622:(parse_args) Unknown parameter HCI
ALSA lib conf.c:4755:(snd_config_expand) Parse arguments error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa:DEV=EB:06:EF:47:83:A6,PROFILE=a2dp,HCI=hci0
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
root@Artisan:~# aplay -D bluealsa:DEV=EB:06:EF:47:83:A6,PROFILE=a2dp /ncsdata/Music/night.mp3
bluealsa: D: ../../src/bluealsa-dbus.c:139: Called: org.bluealsa.Manager1.GetPCMs()
ALSA lib ../../../src/asound/bluealsa-pcm.c:755:(_snd_pcm_bluealsa_open) Couldn't get BlueALSA PCM: PCM not found
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such device
```

mpd is configured for bluealsa

```
audio_output {
        type            "alsa"
        name            "ALSA Bluetooth Headset"
        device          "bluealsa"
        mixer_type    "software"
}
```

Here's what I get trying to play mp3 with mpd:

```
root@Artisan:~# /etc/init.d/mpd start
[ ok ] Starting mpd (via systemctl): mpd.service.
root@Artisan:~# mpc clear
volume: 90%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
ERROR: Failed to open audio output

root@Artisan:~# mpc add night.mp3
root@Artisan:~# mpc play
Unknown artist - Night (Original)
[playing] #1/1   0:00/2:46 (0%)
volume: 90%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
root@Artisan:~# mpc stop
volume: 90%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
ERROR: Failed to open audio output
```

Error messages were identical after setting everything up by 1st and 2nd manuals.
Speaker makes no sound of course. I feel that I'm near the solution, but can't figure out what am I missing. Googling aplay or mpd messages - no luck. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well then, after dancing around and buying another bluetooth receiver I've managed to stream audio on it via bluealsa and mpd.

Here are configs which I've edited:

/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/20-bluealsa.conf

```
# BlueALSA integration setup

defaults.bluealsa.service "org.bluealsa"
defaults.bluealsa.profile "a2dp"
defaults.bluealsa.delay 10000
defaults.bluealsa.interface "hci0"
defaults.bluealsa.device "EB:06:EF:A6:A9:D4"

ctl.bluealsa {
        @args [ SRV BAT ]
        @args.SRV {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.service
                }
        }
        @args.BAT {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.battery
                }
        }
        type bluealsa
        service $SRV
        battery $BAT
}

pcm.bluealsa {
        @args [ SRV DEV PROFILE DELAY ]
        @args.SRV {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.service
                }
        }
        @args.DEV {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.device
                }
        }
        @args.PROFILE {
                type string
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.profile
                }
        }
        @args.DELAY {
                type integer
                default {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.bluealsa.delay
                }
        }
        type plug
        slave.pcm {
                type bluealsa
                service $SRV
                device $DEV
                profile $PROFILE
                delay $DELAY
        }
        hint {
                show {
                        @func refer
                        name defaults.namehint.extended
                }
                description "Bluetooth Audio Hub"
        }
}

pcm {
        type bluealsa
        interface "hci0"
        device "EB:06:EF:A6:A9:D4"
        profile "a2dp"
}

ctl.!default {
        type bluealsa
        interface "hci0"
}
```

/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap --plugin=a2dp
NotifyAccess=main
#WatchdogSec=10
#Restart=on-failure
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service
```

/lib/systemd/system/bluealsa.service

```
[Unit]
Description=BluezAlsa proxy
Requires=bluetooth.service
After=bluetooth.service
[Service]
Type=simple
#User=<user>
#Group=audio
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bluealsa -i hci0 -p a2dp-source -S
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Don't forget to enable bluealsa.service:

```
systemctl enable bluealsa.service
```

~/.asoundrc isn't necessary and removed.

Reboot and this worked for me. The other thing is how it works - unfortunately audio is extremely glitchy. It breaks every half second, not depending on distance between NAS and bluetooth receiver, not depending on file format. Can't understand why and looking for solution. Any ideas?